# How do I check if OSX is in the process of logging out / shutting down?

Tags: macos, qt, logout, shutdown

I'm writing a Qt application and there's a yet-unsolved bug where Qt doesn't pass notifications of logout/shutdown to apps in osx (it works in windows). When you logout/shutdown my app's windows are closed, I'd like to use that time to somehow query osx to see if it's in the process of logging out / shutting down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to register for notifications, you can register for the [NSWorkspaceWillPowerOff](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsworkspace_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIEHCAH) notification, which will call your observer method when either a power-down or a logout is requested.